# Livewire-Laravel-Alpine: Emit event on validation errors including all errors on errorbag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am working on Laravel, Livewire and AlpineJs project, Event can be trigger after validation is passed as shown in code below. But when validation error occurs, code below `$this->validate();` will not run.

How can I emit event for validation error, so that it can be caught in blade file to show small notification like below:

**Register.blade.php**

```
<span x-data="{ open: false }" x-init="
    @this.on('validation-error', () => {
        if (open === false) setTimeout(() => { open = false }, 2500);
            open = true;
        })"
    x-show.transition.out.duration.1000ms="open" style="display: none;" class="text-red-500">Error saving!</span>
```

**Register.php**

```
class Register extends Component
{
    public $name = '';
    public $email = '';
    public $password = '';
    public $password_confirmation = '';

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|same:password_confirmation',
    ];

    public function register()
    {
        $this->validate();
        // $this->emitSelf('validation-error');
        // Here I want to emit event for validation error 
        // and also should capable to get errors from errorbag 

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($this->password),
        ]);

        auth()->login($user);

        // $this->emitSelf('notify-saved');

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

I also tried, but not success, execution doesn't reach here

```
$validator = $this->validate();

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            $this->emitSelf('validation-error');
            return redirect('/register');
                //->withErrors($validator)
                //->withInput();
        }
```

Comment: I think `$errors` will be available within the component, so you can do `$errors->any()` to see whether there are any errors. There's also `@error('email') {{ $message }} @enderror` if you want to put the field's error message next to it

Comment: Sorry, I already implement that, my requirement is to emit events if validation fails

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood - wrap the `$this->validate()` within a try/catch block - `catch ( \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e)` within the catch block fire your event and then optionally `throw $e;` if you want the standard livewire/laravel validation process to continue.

Comment: @alistaircol Thankyou It solved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes as mention in comment, it can be solved by using `trycatch` block.

You can emit event in catch block again validate it so that if errors occurs you can trigger event as well as get all errorbags

```
try {
    $this->validate();
} catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
    $this->emitSelf('notify-error');
    $this->validate();
}
```